# How to check if press outside a component in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I did a custom select but I have the problem to close it if I press outside the select or options. basically the "button" is a `TouchableOpacity` and when I click on it there appears the list of options. But now I can close it only by choosing one option or clicking back on the select button. Is there a way to check whether I click outside the TouchableOpacity or not? In simple react you can give an Id to the component and check it onClick event to see what you have clicked. Or you can use react's `useRef` hook which doesn't seem to work with react-native. I have this code (simplified):

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
const toggle = () => { setIsOpen(!isOpen)}
//...
return (<View>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggle}>
    <Text>Open select</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <View>
    {isOpen && options.map(({value, label}) => <View key={value} onPress={toggle}>{label}</View>)}
  </View>
</View>)
```

As you can see you can call `toggle` only if you press the select button or an option. I want to call `setIsOpen(false)` when I click outside the *TouchableOpacity* box.

Is there a way or library to do it?

Comment: @AshishKamble what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe you can wrap your whole component in TouchableWithoutFeedback which sets isOpen to false when pressed. Would that work for you? https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback

Answer (score 1):

Your safest bid is to use [OutsidePressHandler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-outside-press)

Answer (score 0):

First of all correct usage for toggle function is

```
setIsOpen(prevIsOpen => !prevIsOpen);
```

And regarding your question. Just wrap all screen into touchable component without any feedback.

```
const close = () => isOpen && setIsOpen(false);

return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={close} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggle}>
          <Text>Open select</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View>
          {isOpen && options.map(({value, label}) => <View key={value} onPress={toggle}>{label}</View>)}
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can  use TouchableWithoutFeedback